# Local notification played every time is close the app

Tags: xcode, time, notifications, local, nscalendar

in my app I have a couple lines of code preparing a local notification for 7 am. The problem is that every time I close the app the notification will be showed. I only want this to happen ones after the set time is passed.

In my applicationDidEnterBackground:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar]; // gets default calendar
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]]; // gets the year, month, day,hour and minutesfor today's date
[components setHour:7];
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
UILocalNotification *notifyAlarm = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
if (notifyAlarm) {
    notifyAlarm.fireDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
    notifyAlarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    notifyAlarm.repeatInterval = 0;
    notifyAlarm.soundName = @"not.wav";
    notifyAlarm.alertBody = @"test";
    [app scheduleLocalNotification:notifyAlarm];
}
```

In my applicationWillEnterForeground:

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    NSArray *oldNotifications = [app scheduledLocalNotifications];
    if ([oldNotifications count] > 0) {
        [app cancelAllLocalNotifications];
    }
```

I think the problem is in the [oldNotifications count]. After implementing a NSLog to check it's amount it shows every time 0. This should count up, right?
Any help??? :)

Comment: Is the current time after 7am? Maybe you mean to set it for 7am tomorrow?

Comment: Yes, the current time is after 7 am. I don't mean tomorow, I want it to display a notif. every day at 7

Comment: So, lets say the time now is 10am. You are creating a notification for 3 hours ago. You need to create it for 21 hours in the future.

Comment: I want my app simply to display a local notification every day at 7 am. The problem is that every time I close the app after the passed time it will display again. I only want this to happen ones a day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code. if you want to repeat NSLocalNotification daily then you need to set repeatInterval to NSDayCalender unit.

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar]; // gets default calendar
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]]; // gets the year, month, day,hour and minutesfor today's date
[components setHour:7];
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
UILocalNotification *notifyAlarm = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
if (notifyAlarm)
{
    notifyAlarm.fireDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
    notifyAlarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    notifyAlarm.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
    notifyAlarm.soundName = @"not.wav";
    notifyAlarm.alertBody = @"test";
    [app scheduleLocalNotification:notifyAlarm];
}
```